# Marlin, Ubuntu 11.10 and Dropbox (and Ubuntu One) plugins

Tags: 11.10, dropbox, filemanager, marlin

I have installed `marlin` the elementary OS file manager in my system but I don't see any Dropbox support for it by default, is it available? How can I install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This answer includes instructions on how to add a third-party PPA - proceed with caution.

Yes, after you installed `marlin` with

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install marlin
```

you can then install the Dropbox plugin for `marlin` and since you are at it add the Ubuntu One service plugin

```
sudo apt-get install marlin-plugin-dropbox marlin-plugin-ubuntuone
```

After installing the plugin and the official Dropbox package for Ubuntu you can activate the plugin in `marlin` preferences

[image]

Comment: @jrg thx for the edit, totally forgot about fixing it, too busy!

Comment: No problem, just needed to do this and remembered that you had asked it, saw you didn't update it so i just went and did it. :)

Comment: you get a big + somewhere else!